# How to merge identically structured, nested json files using jq

Tags: json, merge, jq

I need to merge an array in a series of identically structured, nested JSON files that share the same higher level keys.

The goal is to create a merged file while retaining all of the existing, higher level keys and values.

**File 1:**

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "123456",
              "GroupName": "foo"
            },
            {
              "GroupId": "234567",
              "GroupName": "bar"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**File 2:**

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "group_policies": [
            {
              "GroupName": "foo",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_foo",
                "all_bar"                
              ]
            },
            {
              "GroupName": "bar",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_bar"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "123456",
              "GroupName": "foo"
            },
            {
              "GroupId": "234567",
              "GroupName": "bar"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "group_policies": [
           {
              "GroupName": "foo",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_foo",
                "all_bar"                
              ]
            },
            {
              "GroupName": "bar",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_bar"
              ]
            }
           ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following based on answers to other questions of this type with no success:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' test1.json test2.json

jq -s add test1.json test2.json

jq -n '[inputs[]]' test{1,2}.json
```

The following successfully merges the array but lacks the higher level keys and values in the results.

```
jq -s '.[0].regions[0].services[0] * .[1].regions[0].services[0]' test1.json test2.json
```

I am assuming there is a simple jq solution to this that is escaping my searches. If not, any combination of jq and bash will work for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which converts arrays to objects down to the level of services, merges with `*` and converts back to the array form.  If `file1` and `file2` contain the sample data then this command:

```
$ jq -Mn --argfile file1 file1 --argfile file2 file2 '
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[] as $s              # save each element of .services in $s
     | {($a): {($r): $s}}             # generate object for each account,region,service
   # | debug                          # uncomment debug here to see stream                                   
   ;
     reduce merge as $x ({}; . * $x)  # use '*' to recombine all the objects from merge

   # | debug                          # uncomment debug here to see combined object

   | keys[] as $a                     # for each key (account) of combined object
   | {account:$a, regions:[           #  construct object with {account, regions array}
        .[$a]                         #   for each account
      | keys[] as $r                  #    for each key (region) of account object
      | {region:$r, services:[        #     constuct object with {region, services array}
           .[$r]                      #      for each region
         | keys[] as $s               #       for each service
         | {($s): .[$s]}              #         generate service object
        ]}                            #      add service objects to service array
      ]}'                             #   add region object ot regions array
```

produces

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "group_policies": [
            {
              "GroupName": "foo",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_foo",
                "all_bar"
              ]
            },
            {
              "GroupName": "bar",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_bar"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "123456",
              "GroupName": "foo"
            },
            {
              "GroupId": "234567",
              "GroupName": "bar"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### extended explaination

Assembling this step by step provides a better picture of how this works.
Start with just this filter

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | $a
   ;
   merge
```

since there are two objects (one from file1 and one from file2) this outputs
the `.account` from each:

```
"123456789012"
"123456789012"
```

Note that `.account as $a`  does not change the current value of `.`.
Variables allow us to "drill down" into subobjects without losing higher
level context.  Consider this filter:

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | [$a, $r]
   ;
   merge
```

which outputs (account, region) pairs:

```
["123456789012","one"]
["123456789012","one"]
```

Now we can keep drilling down into services:

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[]
     | [$a, $r, .]
   ;
   merge
```

The third element of the array (`.`) at that point refers to each
successive service in the `.services` array, so this filter generates

```
["123456789012","one",{"groups":[{"GroupId":"123456","GroupName":"foo"},
                                 {"GroupId":"234567","GroupName":"bar"}]}]
["123456789012","one",{"group_policies":[{"GroupName":"foo","PolicyNames":["all_foo","all_bar"]},
                                         {"GroupName":"bar","PolicyNames":["all_bar"]}]}]
```

This (complete) merge function:

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[] as $s              # save each element of .services in $s
     | {($a): {($r): $s}}             # generate object for each account,region,service
   ;
   merge
```

produces the stream

```
{"123456789012":{"one":{"groups":[{"GroupId":"123456","GroupName":"foo"},
                                  {"GroupId":"234567","GroupName":"bar"}]}}}
{"123456789012":{"one":{"group_policies":[{"GroupName":"foo","PolicyNames":["all_foo","all_bar"]},
                                          {"GroupName":"bar","PolicyNames":["all_bar"]}]}}}
```

The important thing to observe is that these are objects which can easily be merged with `*`
by a reduce step:

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[] as $s              # save each element of .services in $s
     | {($a): {($r): $s}}             # generate object for each account,region,service
   ;
   reduce merge as $x ({}; . * $x)    # use '*' to recombine all the objects from merge
```

reduce initializes its local state (`.`) to `{}` and then
computes a new state for each result from the merge function
by evaluating `. * $x`, recursively combining the objects merge
built from $file1 and $file:

```
{"123456789012":{"one":{"groups":[{"GroupId":"123456","GroupName":"foo"},
                                  {"GroupId":"234567","GroupName":"bar"}],
                        "group_policies":[{"GroupName":"foo","PolicyNames":["all_foo","all_bar"]},
                                          {"GroupName":"bar","PolicyNames":["all_bar"]}]}}}
```

Note that `*` stopped merging at the array objects in the 'groups' and 'group_policies' keys.
Had we wanted to continue merging we could create more objects in the merge function.  e.g.
consider this extension:

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[] as $s              # save each element of .services in $s
     | (
         $s.groups[]? as $g
       | {($a): {($r): {groups: {($g.GroupId): $g}}}}
       ), (
         $s.group_policies[]? as $p
       | {($a): {($r): {group_policies: {($p.GroupName): $p}}}}
       )
   ;
   merge
```

This merge goes deeper then the previous one, producing

```
{"123456789012":{"one":{"groups":{"123456":{"GroupId":"123456","GroupName":"foo"}}}}}
{"123456789012":{"one":{"groups":{"234567":{"GroupId":"234567","GroupName":"bar"}}}}}
{"123456789012":{"one":{"group_policies":{"foo":{"GroupName":"foo","PolicyNames":["all_foo","all_bar"]}}}}}
{"123456789012":{"one":{"group_policies":{"bar":{"GroupName":"bar","PolicyNames":["all_bar"]}}}}}
```

What is important here is that the "groups" and "group_policies" keys contain objects
which means in this filter

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[] as $s              # save each element of .services in $s
     | (
         $s.groups[]? as $g
       | {($a): {($r): {groups: {($g.GroupId): $g}}}}
       ), (
         $s.group_policies[]? as $p
       | {($a): {($r): {group_policies: {($p.GroupName): $p}}}}
       )
   ;
   reduce merge as $x ({}; . * $x)
```

the reduce `*` will merge groups and group policies instead of overwriting them, generating:

```
{"123456789012":{"one":{"groups":{"123456":{"GroupId":"123456","GroupName":"foo"},
                                  "234567":{"GroupId":"234567","GroupName":"bar"}},
                        "group_policies":{"foo":{"GroupName":"foo","PolicyNames":["all_foo","all_bar"]},
                                          "bar":{"GroupName":"bar","PolicyNames":["all_bar"]}}}}}
```

Putting this back into the original form will require a little more work, but not much:

```
   def merge:                         # merge function
       ($file1, $file2)               # process $file1 then $file2
     | .account as $a                 # save .account in $a
     | .regions[]                     # for each element of .regions
     | .region as $r                  # save .region in $r
     | .services[] as $s              # save each element of .services in $s
     | (
         $s.groups[]? as $g
       | {($a): {($r): {groups: {($g.GroupId): $g}}}}
       ), (
         $s.group_policies[]? as $p
       | {($a): {($r): {group_policies: {($p.GroupName): $p}}}}
       )
   ;
   reduce merge as $x ({}; . * $x)

   | keys[] as $a                     # for each key (account) of combined object
   | {account:$a, regions:[           #  construct object with {account, regions array}
        .[$a]                         #   for each account
      | keys[] as $r                  #    for each key (region) of account object
      | {region:$r, services:[        #     constuct object with {region, services array}
           .[$r]                      #      for each region
         |   {groups:         [.groups[]]}          # add groups to service
           , {group_policies: [.group_policies[]]}  # add group_policies to service
        ]}
      ]}
```

Now with this version suppose our file2 contains a group as well as group_policies. e.g

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "999",
              "GroupName": "baz"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
         "group_policies": [
            {
              "GroupName": "foo",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_foo",
                "all_bar"                
              ]
            },
            {
              "GroupName": "bar",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_bar"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the first version of this solution produced

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "group_policies": [
            {
              "GroupName": "foo",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_foo",
                "all_bar"
              ]
            },
            {
              "GroupName": "bar",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_bar"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "999",
              "GroupName": "baz"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This revised version produces

```
{
  "account": "123456789012",
  "regions": [
    {
      "region": "one",
      "services": [
        {
          "groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "123456",
              "GroupName": "foo"
            },
            {
              "GroupId": "234567",
              "GroupName": "bar"
            },
            {
              "GroupId": "999",
              "GroupName": "baz"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "group_policies": [
            {
              "GroupName": "foo",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_foo",
                "all_bar"
              ]
            },
            {
              "GroupName": "bar",
              "PolicyNames": [
                "all_bar"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the solution. 

This both works and has provided me with something to study to understand why it does so. 8^)

I am somewhat surprised that jq does not provide a more straightforward method to accomplish this goal.

Comment: You're welcome.  The recursive `*` is powerful but as you've discovered it stops recursing at non-object values.  One thing I would suggest is thinking more generally how array data should be merged at the services level.  In the sample data you provided there was no conflict but if file2's services also contained a 'group' this code will replace the group from file1 with the one from file2 which might not be what you want but this is easily remedied once you know how to merge two service arrays.

Comment: RE:  if file2's services also contained a 'group' this code will replace the group from file1 with the one from file2 

Thank you for pointing that out. 

It should not be an issue with these particular AWS data sets but could arise in other uses.

Comment: Could you please provide a step-by-step breakdown of what your solution is doing? 

It would greatly help those of us coming up the jq learning curve to understand this solution and to adapt it to other data sets and situations.

Comment: I've added some comments that may help.  Also try uncommenting some of the [debug](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#debug) commands to get a better picture of the data at those points

Comment: Reading through [basic filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) carefully can be very informative.  Some other good examples can be foundin the [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) and in the jq program section of [rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org)

Comment: I've added an extended explaination showing how to improve how groups and group policies are handled.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort to provide this excellent explicit and accessible explanation of your solution.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

combining `jq add` and jq gives us:

`jq '.hits.hits' logs.*.json | jq -s add`

that will merge all the hits.hits array in all the logs.*.json files into one big array.